# The "new auth dialog" is not opening

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the JS SDK and I have enabled "Enhanced Auth Dialog:" and "Encrypted Access Token". I've setup the "Authenticated Referrals" to require email. When I click preview every thing looks fine. When I attempt to do it from my site I'm get the old auth dialog.

```
$.getScript( "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js", function() {
  FB.init( {
    appId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    channelUrl: MAIN_URL + "/fb-channel.html", // XHR channel to avoid iframe
    oauth: true, // enables OAuth 2.0
    cookie: true, // enable cookies for server-side session access
    status: true, // check login status
    xfbml: false // build via JS
  });


  FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      // ... handles logged in users!
    } else {
      FB.login( function( response ) {
        // Handle login repsonse
      }, /*{scope: "email"}*/}; 
    }
  };
};
```

I have removed the scope parameters as I don't believe they're required any more since I've made them required in Dev App.

What am I doing wrong that the New Auth Dialog isn't showing?